How to remove top padding in SwiftUI List Section header?
I've tried a myriad of parameters suggested in different forums, and none of them seems to reduce the HUGE gap there is above my section header:
List {
    Section {
        // Section Content
    } header: {
        // Header Content
        Text("HEADER")
    }
}


I would even say that the gap in iPad and visionOS could be ok, but in iPhone looks just ridiculous. Any idea to remove (or at least reduce) this padding?
EDIT
I was able to remove the padding by setting .listStyle(.grouped), but unfortunately doing it so prevents sticky header behavior. Anyone who managed to show a plain list with section header without this padding?

Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your current display, see: Minimal code.
Minimal code we can compile and run. The answer probably depends on how you display the List, eg is it in a VStack?

Thank you @workingdogsupportUkraine, the padding appears no matter what I add to the header, even with a simple Text, editing the question for more clarification.
